# Pandoc - Export to multiple HTML files

Tags: html, pandoc

I have a markdown file. for example:

```
# This is a heading
This is a text in a html file
## This is a subheading
This is a text in a subheading

# This is another heading

This is a text in other html file
```

Is it possible to export it to multiple html files, including an index file which looks like this:

```
1. This is a heading
1.1 This is a subheading
2. This is another heading
```

And every heading is a html file, including everything until the next heading. Something like GNU documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [texinfo](https://gnu.org/software/texinfo) for that purpose:

```
pandoc -i file.md -o file.texi
texi2any --html file.texi
```

That will create the 'file' directory, which contains index.html files, and all the nodes.